# Return Flow Guard implementation in Windows SDK 10

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk, windows-10

I tried to implement Return Flow Guard method, described in the [article](https://xlab.tencent.com/en/2016/11/02/return-flow-guard/). It is stated there, that related API is implemented in Windows 10 SDK. However, I found discrepancies in the article content and Microsoft documentation. [GetProcessMitigationPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessmitigationpolicy) function really has a parameter of a type PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY, but it does not have value `ProcessReturnFlowGuardPolicy = 11`. Also, there's no declaration of structure `PROCESS_MITIGATION_RETURN_FLOW_GUARD_POLICY` in Windows 10 SDK header files.

I suspected there are some changes in Windows SDK and structure can be renamed, but I installed all available versions of SDK (Visual Studio 2017 Community online installer): 10.0.10240, 10.0.10568, 10.0.14393, 10.0.15063, 10.0.16299, 10.0.17134 and 10.0.17763, none of them contains declarations I was looking for.

I really don't think the article is fake or something, maybe it was some experimental implementation that was removed/renamed later, does anyone know?

Comment: It was an experimental implementation that was abandoned.

Comment: I see it in ntddk.h in Build 15021  Insider SDK/WDK.

Comment: Can't find, are any comments/notes from Microsoft itself available? If they plan to reimplement

Answer (score 1):

There are no official comments, but all information I collected tells that RFG was discontinued and removed from Windows 10 SDK in early 2018. It could be found in early Insider Windows 10 SDKs, but SDKs released in 2018 already do not include it